# - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application never gets called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to handle phone calls and standby and things of that nature. I added the function

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

to my UIApplicationDelegate. When coming out of standby, "applicationDidBecomeActive" always gets called. However the issue is "applicationWillResignActive" never gets called.

I was wondering if anyone has run into this issue and whether or not anyone found a reason.

**EDIT**

More info, I discovered that my engine's update loop that gets run from applicationDidFinishLaunching was causing me to miss the message. I call

```
while(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, .002, FALSE) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);
```

to catch all iphone messages but it doesn't seem to catch the resignActive message before becoming inactive.

Attempting to fork a thread for my update loop is causing weird crash bugs. Anyone have any quick fix suggestions?

Comment: According to the docs applicationWillResign active gets invoked when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked. If you manually lock the iPhone do you get the call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its getting called in iOS 4.0 , when the Home button is hit.

The following delegate methods are called when the Home button is hit in iOS 4.0

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSLog(@"Application Did Resign Active");
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSLog(@"Application Did Enter Background");
}
```

And when you double tap the home button and again relaunch the App , the following delegate methods are called .

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSLog(@"Application Will Enter Foreground");
}



- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSLog(@"Application Did Become Active");
}
```

Comment: add `NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);` to each appDelegate method instead for a quicker way to print the method you currently reside

Answer (score 2):

I don't think

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

is called when a phone call is received. I think the OS waits for the user to either answer or declines the phone call. If it i declined, then the app says alive and

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

is called. If it is answered, then your app is told to exit and it will receive

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to allow

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

to return before running your game loop. One technique is to use the function

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

on the application delegate and run your game loop after a delay of say ".01" After you do this, the message should be able to fire properly. I believe the reason for the message stomping was because the run loop was stuck on applicationDidFinishLaunching and wasn't able to push any other UIApplicationDelegate messages onto the queue.

Answer (score -2):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
/*
 Sent when the application is about to move from active state to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
 Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
 */
}
```