# logout user if does not touch app for 20 min

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to logout a login user from ipad application if he does not do any thing on app for 20 min. how i can achieve this. I tried

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

this method but no success.

Additional information:
I don't want to terminate, just want to call a method in which I will write code to log out.

Comment: is this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589598/how-to-react-to-applicationwillresignactive-from-anywhere

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964008/voidapplicationwillresignactiveuiapplication-application-never-gets-call

Comment: sorry does not help.Because this method call when some interruption occurs.in my case user is not doing any thing on ipad.even no call.no interruption.just leave for 20 min.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `NSTImer` set to 20 minutes with a target of your logout method and reset it each time there is activity.

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

Comment: no i don't want to terminate.just want to call a method.in which i will write code to log out.